# Scala/Java Project not finding Dependencies during Maven compile

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a Java/Scala hybrid project. When building in Intellij, things work fine. However, trying to run Maven builds from command line is giving me this error when running 'mvn clean install':

```
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:12: error: object model is not a member of package com.test.userlib
    [ERROR] import com.test.userlib.model.cte.{ItemResponse, CteUser}
    [ERROR]                                      ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:13: error: object utils is not a member of package com.test.userlib
    [ERROR] import com.test.userlib.utils.UserLibProperties
    [ERROR]                                      ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:26: error: not found: value UserLibProperties
    [ERROR]       .hosts(UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_HOST + ":" + UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_PORT)
    [ERROR]              ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:32: error: not found: value UserLibProperties
    [ERROR]     ClientAuthTlsConfigUtil.createSslContext(new File(UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_KEYSTORE),UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,new File(UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_TRUSTSTORE),UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD)
    [ERROR]                                                       ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:35: error: not found: type CteUser
    [ERROR]   protected def getUser(dn :String) :CteUser = {
    [ERROR]                                      ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:36: error: not found: value UserLibProperties
    [ERROR]     val rb = RequestBuilder().url(s"${UserLibProperties.CTE_USERSERVICE_ENDPOINT}/user?dn=${URLEncoder.encode(dn,"utf-8")}&aacAttribs=true").buildGet
    [ERROR]                                       ^
    [ERROR] /IdeaProjects/user-lib-common/src/main/scala/com/test/userlib/rest/UserServiceRestClient.scala:42: error: not found: type ItemResponse
    [ERROR]       case HttpResponseStatus.OK => new ObjectMapper().readValue(respTry.get.getContent.toString("UTF-8"), classOf[ItemResponse]).getItem.getUser
    [ERROR]                                                                                                                    ^
    [ERROR] 7 errors found
```

So, clearly my Scala class isn't finding the Java dependencies it needs. Here's my project's structure:

[image]

And here is the build portion of my pom.xml:

```
   <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Do I have to add the classpath to the Scala compiler somehow?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that back then? I know its some time ago but I have the same issue suddenly after some dependency changes (to many to check individually...)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722709) stack overflow answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think UserLibProperties file should be in proper file extension UserLibProperties.scala. Please check you folder and do a list command and check for file extensions, in Intelij it will work without proper extension.

Answer (score -5):

I think, SBT is best way to build a hybrid project.

For example: 
https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/build.sbt

It has little learning curve, but worth to invest time in SBT.